# Strange Happenings With SyntaxHighlighter On Blogger

Tags: blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I've added SyntaxHighlighter to my blog powered by Blogger.

First, all single quotes within a `<pre>` tag, is converted to double quotes on viewing the post. However, when I edit the post, the single quotes are still there. When I try to use `&apos;` or `&#39;` instead, then it gives me a single quote & a double quote.

Second, when I show an example of a `<b:else />` conditional tag use in SyntaxHighlighter, it add's a closing `</b:else />`(there's no such thing) conditional tag. Again, when I go back to edit the post, the `</b:else />` is not there. It only appears on post view. Here is what I'm using:

```
<pre class="brush: xml">
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    STANDARD CONTENT (IF STATEMENT IS TRUE)
<b:else/>
    ALTERNATIVE CONTENT (IF STATEMENT IS FALSE)
</b:if>
</pre>

It appears as:

<b:if cond=""data:blog.pageType" =="item"">
    STANDARD CONTENT (IF STATEMENT IS TRUE)
<b:else>
    ALTERNATIVE CONTENT (IF STATEMENT IS FALSE)
</b:else></b:if>
```

Third, when out `<head>` inside a pre tag, it does not show at all on post view. It's blank, but it's there when I edit.

How do I keep it from doing this? It's messing up my tutorial's...

Comment: 1.)When you edit a post,at the top left,there are 2 options, "Compose" and "HTML".Always work on 1 tab.Even if you click the other once,the initial code changes.2.)Try using another syntax higlighter,perhaps,it would work.

Comment: I already know that Michel. Because of those issues, I only write in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try using anouth syntax highlighter. I use Prism and it works totaly fine.
I wrote a tutorial on how to instal it, if you're interested: http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/2013/04/blogger-syntax-highlighter.html

Comment: This is an old post. I have already switched to Prism and it seems to work way better. Thanks.